# How to load URL from Keyboard ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to load an URL from the keyboard, such that when I click on "DONE" the URL loads in WebView. I tried to use `KeyEvent` but it is not working. How do I do it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are typing something into an edittext then the following can be used to do what you want:

```
    yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                yourWebview.loadUrl(yourEditText.getText());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can have different action depending on what the keyboard says for example "next" or "done", just check the other actions inside EditorInfo.

Let me know if you need any other help.